# mysql sql statement not correct in where clause

Tags: mysql

How can i fix the code for mysql maybe it wrong at m > 10

```
SELECT
    q_mem_tim.Hno,
    q_mem_tim.Moo,
    q_mem_tim.tambol,
    count(*) as m
FROM
    q_mem_tim
WHERE
    m > 10
GROUP BY
    q_mem_tim.Hno,
    q_mem_tim.Moo,
    q_mem_tim.tambol
order by m desc
```

Comment: What's the table structure? I don't really get what you're trying to do here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
    q_mem_tim.Hno,
    q_mem_tim.Moo,
    q_mem_tim.tambol, count(*) as m
FROM
    q_mem_tim
GROUP BY
    q_mem_tim.Hno,
    q_mem_tim.Moo,
    q_mem_tim.tambol
HAVING
    count(*) > 10
order by m desc
```